# Keras: high training and validation accuracy but bad predictions

Tags: keras, lstm

I'm implementing a Bidirectional LSTM in Keras. During the training, either training accuracy and validation accuracy are 0.83 and also losses are 0.45.

```
Epoch 1/50
32000/32000 [==============================] - 597s 19ms/step - loss: 0.4611 - accuracy: 0.8285 - val_loss: 0.4515 - val_accuracy: 0.8316
Epoch 2/50
32000/32000 [==============================] - 589s 18ms/step - loss: 0.4563 - accuracy: 0.8299 - val_loss: 0.4514 - val_accuracy: 0.8320
Epoch 3/50
32000/32000 [==============================] - 584s 18ms/step - loss: 0.4561 - accuracy: 0.8299 - val_loss: 0.4513 - val_accuracy: 0.8318
Epoch 4/50
32000/32000 [==============================] - 612s 19ms/step - loss: 0.4560 - accuracy: 0.8300 - val_loss: 0.4513 - val_accuracy: 0.8319
Epoch 5/50
32000/32000 [==============================] - 572s 18ms/step - loss: 0.4559 - accuracy: 0.8299 - val_loss: 0.4512 - val_accuracy: 0.8318
```

This is my model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I normalized my dataset through `scikit-learn` `StandardScaler`.

I have a custom loss:

```
def get_top_one_probability(vector):
  return (K.exp(vector) / K.sum(K.exp(vector)))

def listnet_loss(real_labels, predicted_labels):
  return -K.sum(get_top_one_probability(real_labels) * tf.math.log(get_top_one_probability(predicted_labels)))
```

These are the `model.compile` and `model.fit` settings:

```
model.compile(loss=listnet_loss, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=1.0, rho=0.95), metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(training_dataset, training_dataset_labels, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=1, 
            epochs=number_of_epochs, workers=10, verbose=1, 
            callbacks=[SaveModelCallback(), keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)])
```

This is my test phase:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(test_dataset)
test_dataset = scaler.transform(test_dataset)

test_dataset = test_dataset.reshape((int(test_dataset.shape[0]/20), 20, test_dataset.shape[1]))

# Read model
json_model_file = open('/content/drive/My Drive/Tesi_magistrale/LSTM/models_padded_2/model_11.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_model_file.read()
json_model_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
model.load_weights("/content/drive/My Drive/Tesi_magistrale/LSTM/models_weights_padded_2/model_11_weights.h5")

with open("/content/drive/My Drive/Tesi_magistrale/LSTM/predictions/padded/en_ewt-padded.H.pred", "w+") as predictions_file:
  predictions = model.predict(test_dataset)
```

I rescaled also the test set. After line `predictions = model.predict(test_dataset)` I put some business logic to process my predictions (this logic is also used in the training phase).

I get very bad results on test set, also if the results in training are good.
What I do in a wrong way?

Comment: You have to re-scale your test set using the mean & sigma from the training dataset. This is easily done by using the StandardScaler instance you used to scale your training dataset, for the test dataset. 
So for the training dataset you call fit & transform on the scaler instance, and then for the test dataset you just use transform (on the same scaler instance). Not sure if that completely fixes your issue, but should def make some difference.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but instead of using the same instance of StandardScaler, I create another instance of it and fitted on training set. Does the StandardScaler scale data in a different way if I only use another instance?

Comment: No that shouldn't matter, however in your code above you are fitting on the test_dataset?
`scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(test_dataset)
test_dataset = scaler.transform(test_dataset)`

Comment: Yeah, but I also tried on training set.

Comment: Not sure in that case then, I would suggest doing some sanity checking, e.g. use your training dataset instead of the testing dataset on the trained model (including any pre-processing etc) to make sure that there are no issues in those steps.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the image generator of Keras works well when combined with fit() or fit_generator() function, but fails  miserably  when combined
with predict_generator() or the predict() function.

When using Plaid-ML Keras back-end for AMD processor, I would rather loop through all test images one-by-one and get the prediction for each image in each iteration.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import keras
import numpy

# code for creating dan training model is not included

print("Prediction result:")
dir = "/path/to/test/images"
files = os.listdir(dir)
correct = 0
total = 0
#dictionary to label all animal category class.
classes = {
    0:'This is Cat',
    1:'This is Dog',
}
for file_name in files:
    total += 1
    image = Image.open(dir + "/" + file_name).convert('RGB')
    image = image.resize((100,100))
    image = numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = numpy.array(image)
    image = image/255
    pred = model.predict_classes([image])[0]
    animals_category = classes[pred]
    if ("cat" in file_name) and ("cat" in sign):
        print(correct,". ", file_name, animals_category)
        correct+=1
    elif ("dog" in file_name) and ("dog" in animals_category):
        print(correct,". ", file_name, animals_category)
        correct+=1
print("accuracy: ", (correct/total))
```